# LLVM: How to find out which type is used?

Tags: c++, llvm, rtti, llvm-ir

I have a llvm::Value. Value::dump() prints

```
void (...)* bitcast (void ()* @test_impl to void (...)*)
```

Usually I would assume that this is a BitCastOperator, however, this class does not seem to exist in llvm 3.4.2 (which I am using, because one of the tools I am working with has not yet been ported to a newer version).

Which subclass of Value is this? And, how can I answer such questions in the future? I tried:

- debugging with lldb. This can only tell me the top-level class.
- accessing rtti info. LLVM seems to have its own RTTI system, which is incompatible with typeid() and has no equivalent to typeid().
- compiling to C++ API code, this would tell me how to create this value and I could see the type from this. However, llc -march=cpp fails with an obscure error (Invalid primitive type) and clang -march=cpp says it does not know this architecture. I confirmed that clang --version and llc --version give the same version number.
- I confirmed that it is NOT a BitCastInst, because a dyn_cast does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> void (...)* bitcast (void ()* @test_impl to void (...)*)
> ```
>
> Which subclass of Value is this?

This is a [constant expression](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions), specifically a bitcast constant expression, represented by [ConstantExpr](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html) class. You can get the opcode using `ConstantExpr::getOpcode` or its string representation using `ConstantExpr::getOpcodeName`.

> bitcast (CST to TYPE)
>
> Convert a constant, CST, to another TYPE. The constraints of the operands are the same as those for the bitcast instruction.

Generally, when you see some opcode applied to constant operands like in this case (as opposed to `bitcast (void ()* %1 to void(...)*)`; glovals vars are constants), you should think of constant expressions first. I really don't think there's a simple way to build a true IR instruction with constant operands when a constexpr counterpart exists.

> And, how can I answer such questions in the future?

You can use `llvm::isa` and `llvm::dynamic_cast`, as you did. During debugging, I find [Value::getValueID](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/35142a98ef1e7581c8a912cfed4c867f98a9204a/include/llvm/IR/Value.h#L424) very useful as well.

> `llc -march=cpp` fails with an obscure error

Side note: CPPBackend has not been updated for a while and has been [removed](https://reviews.llvm.org/rL268631) recently. I'm not surprised it didn't work.